# Override inbuilt feature of record update

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I want to override the inbuilt feature of update row , want to use the same edit image but on click of edit image I want to prevent the default pop up to fade In. Currently I have my custom popup fading in along with inbuilt pop up. I need to prevent the default one. I could not find out any option while configuring Jtable.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this myself. If you don't provide an action for jTables updateAction, you can manually add a column that only contains the edit button image and a link handler.

Sample code would be like this, note that there is no updateAction defined.

```
actions: {
            listAction: '/Controller/ListFunction',
            deleteAction: '/Controller/DeleteFunction'
        }
```

And then add a column like this:

```
Edit: {
                list: true,
                edit: false,
                display: function (data) {
                    var $img = $('<img class="child-opener-image" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/edit.png")" />');
                    $img.click(function () {
                        window.location = '/Controller/EditFunction?RecordId=' + data.record.RmaId
                    });
                    return $img;
                }
            }
```

This was lifted from one of my own projects so will need a little editing on your part, but that should point you in the right direction.